# WPF Performance Suite - strange app behaviour

Tags: wpf, kinect

I am working on a project including WPF and OpenNI library with sensor usage. My application is very simple, I am getting hand points from sensor device and drawing two rectangles using data binding. When I'm launching my app, rectangles are drawn with very big lag, but strange thing is, when I start WPF Performance Suit, lag suddenly stops and application is working perfectly.

My question is, what WPF Performance Suit is doing to running application and how I can recreate the same behavior in code without using this program?

Thanks for any help.